# не отправляется фото с ajax запроса в php файл

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, база-данных

есть файл js с ajax запросом, этот запрос должен отправить изображение в php файл, который сохранит это фото в папку media, а название фото сохранит в БД.

php файл changeData.php

```
function savePhoto($photo) {
    $fileSuccess = 'No';
    $fileName = $photo['name'];
    $fileTmp = $photo['tmp_name'];

    $uploadFolder = 'media/';

    $moveFile = move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $uploadFolder . $fileName);

    if ($moveFile) {
        $fileSuccess = 'photo uploaded successful';
    }

    $user = R::findOne('users', 'id = ?', array($_SESSION['logged user']->id));
    if ($user) {
        $user->photo = $fileName;
        $_SESSION['logged user'] = $user;
        R::store($user);
        echo 'success';
    }
}
$userPhoto = $_FILES['photo'];

if (isset($userPhoto)) {
    savePhoto(($userPhoto));
}
```

```js
function renderImg(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    photoPreviewNode.innerHTML = `<img src="${e.target.result}" alt="photo">`
  }
  reader.onerror = function(e) {
    alert('error')
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file.files[0])
}

$('.addPhotoForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let fd = new FormData();
  let photo = $('.photoInput')[0].files;
  fd.append('photo', photo[0])

  $.ajax({
    url: 'changeData.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: renderImg(inputPhoto)
  }).done(function() {
    console.log(1)
    alert(1)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">Photo</div>

  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="addPhotoForm column">
    <div class="column">
      <label for="photoInput">Add photo</label>
      <button type="submit" class="button formPhotoFormButton">Change</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column photoPreview">
      <input name="photo" type="file" class="photoInput" id="photoInput" placeholder="add photo" style="display:none">
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос в чём заключается?

Comment: ты запрос отправляешь на файл....... но метод-то никак не отрабатывает

Comment: нужно чтобы php файл получил фото и отправил его в бд, а сам файл добавил в папку media

Comment: нужно - ок......... а проблема-то в чём?

Comment: Опять же. ты запрос отправляешь на файл....... но метод-то никак не отрабатывает

Comment: массив $_FILES пустой

Comment: Где в представленном коде массив FILES?

Comment: извините, сейчас вставлю этот кусок в вопрос

Comment: Воспользуйся отладкой.....точнее так..... прочитай все ответы в тех дубликатах, что висят выше. Обязательно! Прямо сегодня и по многу раз......... в целом... если бы ты это уже читал, то ты бы увидел ошибки в консоли....... а всё потому, что писать так `success: renderImg(inputPhoto)` - некорректно........ надо вставлять ссылку на функцию `success: renderImg`  или писать анонимную фунцию........ в целом тема отладки и нахождения ошибок - очень важна для разработчиков, так что срочно изучать

Comment: спасибо большое! обязательно прочту и изучу, но если удалить строку success: renderImg(inputPhoto), фото тоже не отправляется в файл php

Comment: не удалить а заменить........ вполне отправляется....... либо у тебя путь неверный до обработчика

Comment: путь верный, 100%

Comment: смотри консоль, network отправки данных и отладку...... я воспроизвёл данный код.... если заменить код, как я привёл выше - всё отправляется и в FILES есть данные ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   ..... возможно ещё а) в кэше данные остались - надо разрабатывать без кэширования....... и ты мог забыть сохранить файл после внесения изменений.

Comment: кэш браузера очистил, файл сохраняю всегда, в вкладке network есть отправка, но когда я в самом файле changeData.php делаю var_dump($_FILES), то на странице выведено NULL, не знаю что не так(